# NavigationStack is not updated successfully in Xamarin forms iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin forms project and I use custom master detail page. So I have MasterDetailPage and NavigationPageRenderer in Xamarin iOS and Xamarin Android project. I want to navigate as follows

```
var mdp = App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
await mdp.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
await mdp.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
await mdp.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page3());
await mdp.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page4());
await mdp.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page5());
await mdp.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page6());
```

I have a NavigationStack of 6 elements and I want to go Page2 from Page6. So I did the following operations

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  mdp.Detail.Navigation.RemovePage(mdp.Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack[mdp.Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
}
await mdp.Detail.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

I remove pages between Page6 and Page 2 and then I remove last page(Page6) with PopAsync. This worked successfully in android project. But it's not working in iOS project. The stack successfully changed in the iOS project, but view is not updated successfully. The screen appears as the title of page 6 and white screen. Page2 doesn't appear.

I tried the following

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await mdp.Detail.Navigation.PopAsync());
```

and

```
await mdp.Detail.Navigation.PopAsync(true);
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Can you share a sample so that I can reproduce the issue?